# Why is F# having a problem with partially overlapping module names?

Tags: f#

This one always gets me, and I fail to understand the problem the F# compiler is having here.

I have two files for two modules.

A.fs:

```
module A
//rest of the module goes here
```

B.fs

```
module A.B
//rest of the module goes here
```

When I build this project, I get:
`A.fs(1, 8): [FS0247] A namespace and a module named 'A' both occur in two parts of this assembly`

Why? There is nothing else in the project, other than the Program.fs. Am I wrong to assume I can break down modules into multiple files to keep things under control, while using a namespace like naming scheme? (obviously the compiler thinks so).

I want to understand the problem the compiler is having here and why I'm presented an error that refers to namespaces, even though I have no namespace declarations in my code.

Comment: I saw this recently in an Fable project 2 project when the sdk (dotnet 5 instead of 3) version was wrong and string interpolation was used. So this could be due some other error in module A

Comment: Nothing complicated. Just a simple F# project. I've seen this before many times. I just changed the module name and got over it but I was being lazy. I'd like to learn the underlying problem here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an answer to this question, just in case someone encounters the same error and googles their way here.

This bit from [the modules documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules) explains what is going on:

> In the syntax for the top-level module declaration, the optional
> qualified-namespace is the sequence of nested namespace names that
> contains the module.

By declaring a module as `A.B` I'm actually declaring a module `B` in namespace `A` as per the above description. So I'm ending up with a module named `A` due to
 `module A` and a namespace `A` due to `module A.B` and the compiler is telling me that I now have both a module and a namespace named `A` in this assembly.

I'll change this answer or un-accept it in case I'm wrong.

Comment: that should be perfectly right. you can verify this by inspecting the assembly with ildasm or dotpeek: f# modules are classes in msil, so you should see nested classes.

Comment: Thanks @citykid I'll take your advice re dotpeek.

Comment: There is a way around this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75997727/split-large-top-level-module-into-several-files