# Split large top-level module into several files

Tags: f#

Here's something I've been struggling with in F# lately.

Given a top-level module:

```ml
module MyApp.Components

module Link =
    let text = ()

module User =
    let avatar = ()

let table = ()
```

Note that it has some top-level functions (e.g. `table`) and some functions grouped by concept using modules. After `open MyApp` I can then use `Components.table` or `Components.Link.text`.

Now assume that this file grows over time and I want to split it up into several files preserving the structure. Is that possible? The closest I can think of is this file structure

```
MyApp/
  Components/
    Link.fs
    User.fs
    Globals.fs
```

where `Link.fs` would look like this

```ml
module MyApp.Components.Link

let text = ()
```

and `User.fs` analogous to that. `Global.fs` would make use of `AutoOpen` as follows:

```ml
[<AutoOpen>]
module MyApp.Components.Globals

let table = ()
```

Now that works with the big caveat that I have to `open MyApp.Components` in order for the `AutoOpen` to work.

But what if I still want to only `open MyApp`? As far as I understand, if I have a top-level `module MyApp.Components.Link`, then I can't also define a top-level `module MyApp.Components`.

I feel like this should be possible, but I'm afraid it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current best solution with the `Globals` module marked with `AutoOpen` is quite good - but there may be one more trick that could work in some cases.

In F#, there is a difference between *namespaces* and *modules*. A module can contain top-level definitions and is compiled into a .NET class with static fields. A namespace can only contain classes and modules and is compiled into a .NET class. Another important constraint is that modules have to be defined all in a single file.

If you define `module MyApp.Components.Link`, you are defining a module `Link` (compiled as a class) inside a namespace `MyApp.Components`. This means that you cannot define a module `MyApp.Components` elsewhere (because it would clash with the namespace name).

However, F# has a trick that lets you force the compiler to add `Module` suffix to a compiled representation of an F# module (while the name still looks normal to the F# code). This means that you can do the following:

**Link.fs**

```
module MyApp.Components.Link
let text = ""
```

**Globals.fs**

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module MyApp
let table = ""
```

**Main.fs**

```
module Main
open MyApp

printfn "%A" (Components.Link.text + table)
```

This works because the `MyApp` module in `Globals.fs` is actually compiled as `MyAppModule`. The limitation is that you can only have one file that defines globals.